# Cassandra's "get_count" asymptotic time complexity

Tags: cassandra

On the [Cassandra's API description](http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/API) it is stated that `get_count` is not O(1). What is it time complexity then? At most O(log(n)), I expect!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks O(n) to me. You have to count every column (though you don't necessarily go over the network every time).

Take a look at [this discussion on the Cassandra JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-674?focusedCommentId=12839395&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#action_12839395), especially Jonathan Ellis's comment about *why* this is the case: it's a tradeoff.

Comment: If you do go read that ticket, start with David Strauss's comment near the bottom, then continue to my reply.  The discussion that precedes it is long and not relevant to counting. :)